# how to print data in 10000 line per file in text file

Tags: python, pandas, printing, split

I am have to make combination of certain data, the data is available in excel file. but combination amount of lines in millions. so I want to print 50000 lines per file.

My Code is.(which make a single file in text format, but want to print 50000 lines per file)

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", header=None, index_col=False, dtype=str)
df.columns = ['A']

comb = list(itertools.product(df['A'], repeat=4))
a = comb

for x in range(len(a)):
    print(a[x], file=open('comb.txt', 'a'))
```

Comment: is it 10000 or 50000 per file?

Comment: Look at the `grouper` recipe in the `itertools` documentation; it lets yo uiterat over `comb` in chunks of 50,000; you'll write each chunk to a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 0
lines = []
for item in itertools.product(df['A'], repeat=4)):
    lines.append(''.join(item))

    if len(lines) > 50000:
        with open(f'comb.{i}.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(lines))
        lines = []
        i += 1
```

Comment: 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance', tuple found. in my excel file it having codes. like AA, AB, AC...... ANY solutions for that